# How to get response right after execution of block in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, afnetworking, block

I am using `AFNetworking` framework to call the web service and i have used 
POST method to get response from the web service like that :

```
       AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
               manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
               [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:25];
               [manager POST:stringURL parameters:param
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                   NSLog(@"RESPONCE : %@", responseObject);
                 } 
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
                {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
               NSString *msg = error.localizedDescription;
               UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"That Shift" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
              [alertview show];
                                  }];
        NSLog(@"Right AFter Block Execution RESPONCE : %@", responseObject);
```

i want my response right after its execution in `NSLog(@"Right AFter Block Execution RESPONCE : %@", responseObject);` can any one suggest me how can i do that ?

**REASON BEHINDE DOING THAT :**

The reason behind doing that is i want to use another block right after that code which i have given and i want to use that responce in second block which will be right after that in the plce of `NSLog(@"Right AFter Block Execution RESPONCE : %@", responseObject);`.

Comment: You can't as the operation is asynchronous.

Comment: What is wrong with putting that inside the success block ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use semaphores to synchronize your threads, so the first thread will block and wait for second. But do not do it on main thread since your GUI will freeze.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
// Inside callback:
 dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
// Before NSLOG
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, <timeout_may_be_forever>);
```

Comment: Why not simply do it in the "success block"?

Comment: @trojanfoe I am not topic starter, I do not know;)